# Install packages in a cluster

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, redhat, cloudera, yum

I'm trying to prepare a cluster to install cloudera hadoop distribution, and I have to install some [packages](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_c.html#install_package_dependencies) using `yum install` command.

All nodes of my cluster are not connected to internet except the master.

Does there any way to make `yum` in each slave node, passes through the master to the internet, or to install from the master as repository ?

NB: I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be nice to run proxy (e.g. [squid](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-squid-configuration.html) which is in the distribution repos) on host which is connected to the internet and then use `proxy=http://ip_proyxserver:3128/` in `/etc/yum.conf` on the clients.